# What is the equivalent of python's "window.get_property("visible") in GTK+ (C)?

Tags: user-interface, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

In order to show some window upon a clicking a button in the main window, i have to use "on_delete_event" signal to show or hide the appropriate windows. I know the pygtk "window.get_property("visible")". I searched the documentation there is no such thing as gtk.get
_property all i found was "gtk.mnemonics.get_visible or something like this.

I'm pretty sure somebody has used show and hide stuff in GTK+(C)

Answer (score 2):

The functions you want are [`g_object_get()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get) and [`g_object_set()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set). These apply to all GObjects, not just GtkWidget.

In the case of GtkWidget's `"visible"` property there is also a [`gtk_widget_get_visible()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-visible) function (and a [`gtk_widget_is_viisble()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-is-visible) function that also checks all parents of a GtkWidget) and an equivalent `gtk_widget_set_visible()`.

Remember that GtkWindow is derived from GtkWidget; the former will use the latter's methods and properties where appropriate.